# Combine two config files as an a single file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project with 3 subprojects:**AdminPages**, **UserPags** ,**UIpages**,each part has a separate files.for example **AdminPages** is coded by MVC4, **Userpages** and **Uipages** is coded by ASP web form .

So i have 2 config files,my question is can i combine these two files into single file?Or i have to put each project in a special subdomain ?

Thanks.If i can i will add config files to this post.

Answer (score 0):

With a little google, I came to an answer where it was stated that you can use: [XmlConfigMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7406/XmlConfigMerge-Merge-config-file-settings).

A qoute from the site:

> The XmlConfigMerge utility (provided both as a library assembly and as a console application) supports this merging of XML .config files, and also supports setting of specific parameters via XPath filtering and optional Regex pattern matching.

Go there and try their code and documentation. Good luck!